# Change the content of map pop up real time, Leaflet js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In Leaflet, Im showing a map with pop up showing information about the selected area.
This is my code

```
L.geoJson(territories, {
    style: function(feature) {
          return {color: "#328CFA"};
    }
}).bindPopup(poupcontent).addTo(map);
```

The variable poupcontent has the data to be shown in the pop up.
I have some filtering options in my site.
Now what I need is to filter the content shown in the pop up in real time, according to the filters applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better answer.Calling the bindpopup function inside the filter function will worked for me.ie

```
var territories = L.geoJson(territories, {
    style: function(feature) {
          return {color: "#328CFA"};
    }
}).addTo(map);

territories.bindPopup(poupcontent);
```

call `territories.bindPopup(newpoupcontent);` inside the filter function with the new content

Answer (score 0):

A popup is a plain HTML, which is dynamically inserted into a page and can be enclosed, for example, in `<div id="popupcontent">...</div>`. With that you can access the content with `document.getElementById('popupcontent').innerHTML` and change it however you like.